# How do I enable/disable buildings and structures on SMP?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, server-administration

As Minecraft has gotten its full release I'm working on a server for the local scouting group. I'm a system administrator and developer and used to host HL2 servers.

While the Minecraft single-player client has an option to turn on (or off) buildings and structures, the Minecraft multiplayer server doesn't seem to have one?

Is there a way to turn this on?

Comment: The default server settings are automatically on. I don't know if there's any way to turn it off.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A [server-setting](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Server.properties) was added in 1.1 to control this. If your `server.properties` contains

```
generate-structures=false
```

before you generate the world, and there will be no structures. The default is `true`, so to turn it on instead you just leave that setting alone.

---

*An alternative answer that works for all versions:*

The flag is stored within the world's `level.dat`, meaning you can generate a world in single-player with structures disabled and then move it to your server. This works generally, and is the easiest way to do it prior to 1.1.

Answer (score 1):

There also is a way to edit your existing world. You can use the `NBTedit` tool ([here](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/6661-nbtedit/)) to edit the `level.dat` file.

Comment: `level.dat` doesn't exist until the world is created, at which point structures may already exist and editing it won't remove those. (Consider the example of a village right beside the spawn point.)